# How to select value of a particular dropdown in a given row with multiple dropdown options?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many forms with two dropdown options name and value and I want option of name to be selected be a variable from an array, something like this.

```
for (i = 0;i<noOfElements;i++)
           {
                var resultHtml = theModule.getHtml("rowformtemplate", {});
            //load html of form with fields **name** and **value** as dropdown
                $(section).append(resultHtml);
            //append html to a div
                var optValue = namearray[i];
            //from list of optons this value should be selected
                var form = $(section).find(".row-template");
            //find all forms in the section
                var row= form[form.length-1];
            //select latest form
            //How to select name field "name" of current row and set it to be optvalue which is a variaable something like this. but it selects name field of all form and sets it to optValue 
                $("select[name^='name'] option[value=" + optValue + "]").attr("selected","selected");
            }
```

Comment: I stopped reading after a few lines, please post some code and proper readable paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

In your final jquery selector, you are looking through the full html document instead of the latest form.

Try the following

```
$(row).find("select[name='name'] option[value='" + optValue + "']").attr("selected","selected");
```

or if using latest jquery

```
$(row).find("select[name='name'] option[value='" + optValue + "']").prop("selected",true);
```

Also check
[How do I select item with class within a DIV in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933763/how-do-i-select-item-with-class-within-a-div-in-jquery)

[How do you select a particular option in a SELECT element in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/how-do-you-select-a-particular-option-in-a-select-element-in-jquery)